# Orbiting Turtles Around a Stationary Circle

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I am trying to make 4 turtles orbit around a single circle. I need help with either loop placement or structures of the loop. I can get one turtle to loop, but the 3 others stay stationary.

```
import turtle as trtl

array = []

x=0
middle = trtl.Turtle()
trtl.shape("circle")

turtle = trtl.Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.goto(44, 0)
turtle.setheading(90)
array.append(turtle)

turtle2 = trtl.Turtle()
turtle2.penup()
turtle2.speed(1)
turtle2.goto(0, 44)
turtle2.setheading(180)
array.append(turtle2)

turtle3 = trtl.Turtle()
turtle3.penup()
turtle3.speed(1)
turtle3.goto(0, -44)
turtle3.setheading(0)
array.append(turtle3)

turtle4 = trtl.Turtle()
turtle4.penup()
turtle4.speed(1)
turtle4.goto(-44, 0)
turtle4.setheading(270)
array.append(turtle4)

while turtle in array:
turtle.circle(44)

while turtle2 in array:
turtle2.circle(44)

while turtle3 in array:
turtle3.circle(44)

while turtle4 in array:
turtle4.circle(44)

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I know this should be simple, but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You have four loops in sequence: only one turtle at a time can move!
Since you made each of those an infinite loop, you'll never get to the second turtle at all!

The following loop will let each turtle make a lap in turn, until each has done 5 laps.  Does that get you un-stuck?

```
for laps in range(5):
    turtle.circle(44)
    turtle2.circle(44)
    turtle3.circle(44)
    turtle4.circle(44)
```

Comment: Yes, quite.  Given the current programming level, I presume that simultaneous orbits are *not* what the assignment calls for.

Comment: My assignment calls for turtle movement, but I see I'm going far out of my skill range.